# Corrupt Ubuntu Server ISO images

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, iso

This is the 3rd time I've downloaded ubuntu-12.04.4-server-amd64.iso from the Ubuntu site, and even then I get the message in the screenshot below.

Have any of you had this problem? I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. I'm downloading using Chrome without splitting the file into pieces (like an accelerator would do).

Is there something wrong with the ISOs themselves, or is this a Windows problem? The MD5s never match.

I'm doing all this on a Dell Laptop with 4GB RAM running Windows 7 Home Premium 64.

Can someone help?

Edit: I'm trying to get it running on Oracle's Virtual Box. Am I wrong in using the 64Bit ISO? It say's AMD64 but I've got Intel :-)

[image: Somewhere through the installation]

When I run check cd-rom, I get this:
[image]

Comment: When you download the iso, does the md5 sum matches the one listed in the download page?

Comment: They never do. No matter how I download. That's the strangest thing.

Comment: I am referring to the md5 sum of the iso itself. ( http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/MD5SUMS )

Comment: The MD5 of the ISOs do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing from the ISO itself, or are you recording it in a CD or DVD? Because the problem might be in the recording, not in the ISO.

Try to check the MD5 for the iso file first, before burning it to disk. If that's correct, then the corrupted files happen when you build the CD. I would advice to use a bootable USB for the installation instead of a CD or DVD (you'll save time and won't waste any more discs).

[Here](http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu-releases/12.04.4/) you can get the ISO files an its corresonding hash files. To check a hash in Windows (if you have not Ubuntu installed) there are dozens of little programs around like md5sum

Comment: I'm installing from the ISO itself, which is in the downloads directory. The MD5s do not match. I'm trying to get it running on Oracle Virtual Machine.

Comment: That's weird... try a different mirror and download the ISO and the MD5 hash from that mirror. If it fails again, your ISP or Windows itself are doing something weird with your downloads.

Comment: Is this problem caused because I'm using the 64Bit ISO? My Dell has a i5 2450M CPU.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason... an i5 is a 64bit processor, and anyway if the problem was the CPU you won't even be able to boot the ISO.